# How to use single inputTextField for accept two inputs and generates output in Visual Force?

Tags: apex, visualforce

For Example i need to add two numbers?  So how is it possible with

```
   <apex:inputText value="somevalue" action ="{!action}"/>
```

With this single inputText and On clicking the button , the values in the text field should be passed to the controller class and generates output.

Comment: So, for example, you are entering "1,2" in your text field and on button click you should get 3 ?

Comment: Yes but using only one inputText Field.

Comment: Suppose if You Want to Create a calculator using single   <apex:inputText value="somevalue" />   how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

Apex Page:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="testing">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:input value="{!addthis}"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!add}" value="Add"/>
        <apex:outputLabel >{!result}</apex:outputLabel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class testing {

    public Integer result { get; set; }
    public String addthis{get; set;}
    public List<Integer> IntList = new List<Integer>();

    public PageReference add() {
        Integer sum = 0;
        List<String> str = addthis.replace(' ','').split(',');
        for(String s : str){
            Integer i = Integer.ValueOf(s);
            sum = sum +i;
        }
        result = sum;
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Update**: If you want result in same input text:

Page:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="testing">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:input value="{!addthis}"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!add}" value="Add"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class testing {

    //public Integer result { get; set; }
    public String addthis{get; set;}
    public List<Integer> IntList = new List<Integer>();

    public PageReference add() {
        Integer sum = 0;
        List<String> str = addthis.replace(' ','').split(',');
        for(String s : str){
            Integer i = Integer.ValueOf(s);
            sum = sum +i;
        }
        addthis = sum+'';
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: What should i do to display value in same inputText Field?

Comment: instead of outputlabel line, use `<apex:inputText value="{!result}"/>` . Oops I didnt read the question updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

action is not a supported attribute of `<apex:inputText>`

Not sure why you want to get this but here is the example code: 
Page:

```
<apex:inputText value="myText"/>
<apex:commandButton value="submit" action="{!submit}"/>
```

Controller:

```
public class theController 
{
    public String myText {get; set;}
    public Integer actualField {get; set;}

    public void submit()
    {
        public List<String> numberList = myText.split(',');
        if(numberList.size() == 0)
            actualField = 0;
        else if(numberList.size() == 1)
            actualField = Integer.valueOf(numberList[0]);
        else if(numberList.size() > 1)
            actualField = Integer.valueOf(numberList[0] + numberList[1]);
        //You need to write the error handling code yourself
        //...

    }
}
```